# Better way to represent tabular data examples

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add support for tables in answers and questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/please-add-support-for-tables-in-answers-and-questions)

I've seen tons of question that have (or need) some example data - but **there is no easy-to-use way to present tabular data** on SO, so users "invented" different approaches to accomplish this:

- copy-paste rows from excel or database output (yes, this will end up as unreadable inline text that other users have to correct):
  ID  Name_ID Amount
  1   1   50
  2   1   100
  3   2   50
  4   2   100
- pre, code or manually inserting spaces:

  ```
  ID  Name_ID Amount
  1   1   50
  2   1   100
  3   2   50
  4   2   100
  ```
- [3rd party formatting sites](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

  ```
  ╔════╦═════════╦════════╗
  ║ ID ║ Name_ID ║ Amount ║
  ╠════╬═════════╬════════╣
  ║  1 ║       1 ║     50 ║
  ║  2 ║       1 ║    100 ║
  ║  3 ║       2 ║     50 ║
  ║  4 ║       2 ║    100 ║
  ╚════╩═════════╩════════╝
  ```
- images:

  [image: example of tabular data]

I propose adding a new icon / icons before **Code Sample**, e.g. **Input Data Sample** and **Output Data Sample**, like this:

[image]

- result could be actual HTML table - possibly with headers for fist row, with a right-floating icon or text to distinguish between input and output data:

  [image]

Comment: ASCII art. Just use ASCII art. Trust me.

Comment: it would be helpfull to differentiate between wanted output data an current (wrong) output, e.g. blue/red background instead of gray...

Comment: @BoltClock tell that to every beginner here, who tend to prefer the first (inline) method.. actually, this can be a solution, add a link to ascii art formatting site to the help texts..