# Can we add Markdown support for tables?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, markdown, tables

This is similar to: [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/167523) and [Please add support for tables in answers and questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5255/167523), but is slightly different. The other questions are asking more of a why question, not a please do this question. I am asking for a specific implementation of Markdown tables. I found [an article](https://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2008/08/tables-for-markdown-and-textmate/) on making tables in Markdown using [PHP Markdown](https://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) or [MultiMarkdown](https://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/). The code to make a table looks like this:

```
| Left align | Right align | Center align |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| This       |        This |     This     |
| column     |      column |    column    |
| will       |        will |     will     |
| be         |          be |      be      |
| left       |       right |    center    |
| aligned    |     aligned |   aligned    |
```

And the result is:

[image: rendering of above table Markdown]
This is much different than [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5258/167523), which says that Jeff doesn't want the `<tr><td>` tags allowed on the SE sites. This request has a specific feature request, as opposed to the other questions which don't really have a decisive yes/no answer.

Here are some specific posts that need this type of support:
[Where can I find the Unicode symbols for Mac functional keys? (Command, Shift, etc.)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55729/7833)
[Is there a way to directly link requirements to code units?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135055/843322)

Comment: I find the need for left and right borders cumbersome, but otherwise this has potential

Comment: That code is really not the most user-friendly thing I've seen. Aren't there better ways? And the second question you linked to is actually a `[friend-request]` where the Moderator-only tag `[status-bydesign]` is kind of a decisive "no" answer. By the way, I'd like the table support.

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm out of votes for today. @JoelCoehoorn If you mean you want no vertical bars to the left and the right of each line, I'd disagree. Then the system would interpret every line like `one | two` as a table, especially when you'd least expect it!

Comment: @Alenanno Yes I know and realize that the status-bydesign tag was on the question. However, I'd like to see a real answer. I also think my solution is one of, if not the best way to implement tables. In regards to other ways, I haven't seen anything else.

Comment: This question is still a duplicate of "[Please add support for tables in answers and questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/please-add-support-for-tables-in-answers-and-questions)", which specifically asks for the feature. And it has a decisive answer: ***NO***.

Comment: @NicolBolas I would argue that it isn't a duplicate. My question has a Markdown specific request, not a Google Charts API request. Therefore, the question is the same, but the implementation that I'm asking for is much different.

Comment: @daviesgeek: He didn't ask for Google Charts. He just posted that as a workaround.

Comment: Funny, I saw this shortly after [rescuing this old link only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1388596/revisions) and was thinking *'Ya know, I hate the idea of Markdown tables until I need to make one, then I like the idea for a few days.'* The developers have historically rejected anything not in the markdown standard and I support that, but perhaps we're big enough to _influence_ the standard provided a suitable implementation can be hashed out?

Comment: @TimPost That would be nice! :-)

Comment: FWIW, I prefer GitHub's implementation, as simple as pipe-delimited list but supports the full format if you need it. https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#wiki-tables

Answer (score 17):

I don't think we need to request support for tables *via Markdown specifically*, but I agree that tables would be helpful.  On several SE sites, [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139160/when-should-i-use-cross-apply-over-inner-join) [with](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/can-mysql-reasonably-perform-queries-on-billions-of-rows) [tables](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29203/check-for-database-tampering) [could](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/55345) [be](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2654) [improved](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30830/what-happens-when-an-embedded-program-finishes/30840#30840) [if](https://superuser.com/questions/103915/access-merge-two-databases-with-identical-structure) table support is added ([or](https://askubuntu.com/a/248534/12840) [spreadsheets!](https://superuser.com/questions/234997/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-eating-my-delicious-csv-files-and-excreting-useless-da)).  On gaming.SE, things like [Minecraft crafting layouts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bminecraft%5D+craft+is%3Aquestion) would be possible without embedding images.  I also started building a [specific list](https://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/add-support-for-tables) of questions over on Scifi.SE that I think would be helped, as many concrete examples always help bolster a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: I've seen many answers with tables, but they are always _screenshots_ of a table, and that causes a lot of inconsistency...

Answer (score 13):

Over on DBA.SE, this would matter more than on most sites, but we have had [our feature-request](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/963/1396) declined ([too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/166851)).

However, if I recall correctly, Anna Lear said there was some hope of a user-script being incorporated into the site if we can write one ourselves and get a good number of folk using it before raising the request again.

I don't know how to do this, but perhaps someone else would like to take the 'proof of principle' bit of jQuery I wrote and turn it into a proper script?

Jake Feasel has already kindly changed SQLFiddle to generate 'normal' markdown for tables like this:

```
a table:
    
|Item    |Value|
|--------|----:|
|Computer|$1600|
|Phone   |  $12|
|Pipe    |   $1|
```

Here's the code I came up with (tested on Firefox only and missing the justification feature):

```js
$('div.post-text>pre').each(function() {
    $(this).children().html($(this).children().html().replace(/(^\|.*\|$\n)+/gm, function(match) {
        var index = 0;
        return '<table style="margin: 0.5em; table-layout: fixed; font-size: smaller; background-color: white; box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #777;">' + match.replace(/^(.*)$/gm, function(match) {
            var cell = 'th';
            index++;
            if (index === 2) {
                return '';
            }
            if (index > 2) {
                cell = 'td';
            }
            return '<tr>' + match.replace(/^\|/, '<' + cell + '>').replace(/\|$/, '</' + cell + '>').replace(/\|/, '</' + cell + '><' + cell + '>') + '<tr>';
        }) + '</table>';
    }));
}).find('td,th').css('border', '1px solid black').css('padding', '2px').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
}).filter('th').css('background-color', '#eee')
```

Here's a screenshot of the output for those who can't run the script:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

In sites where snippets are enabled, you can create code that renders the table. Just write it down by hand if you know how or use an online table editor.

I used [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables) to create this nice Spanish verbs table for [SSE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) (just remember to save your work in .tng before leaving just in case you need some edit in the future).

Too bad we have code snippets disabled there. I think this would be a good reason to allow snippets in more SE sites (well... all of them?). I don't believe this would be riskier than enabling them here, for example. What's more, my table has no JS so what's the danger?

```css
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-yj5y{background-color:#efefef;border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-b7v7{color:#000000;border-color:inherit;text-align:right;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-m223{font-size:100%;border-color:#000000;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-7btt{font-weight:bold;border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-dvpl{border-color:inherit;text-align:right;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-fbe1{font-style:italic;background-color:#efefef;border-color:inherit;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-eiws{font-weight:bold;color:#000000;border-color:inherit;text-align:right;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-fymr{font-weight:bold;border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-r9b6{font-size:100%;color:#000000;border-color:inherit;text-align:right;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-73oq{border-color:#000000;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-6ic8{font-weight:bold;border-color:inherit;text-align:right;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-mcqj{font-weight:bold;border-color:#000000;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7btt" colspan="4">No personales<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dvpl">Infinitivo</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amar</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">haber amado</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Infinitivo compuesto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dvpl">Participio</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amado</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dvpl">Gerundio</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amando</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">habiendo amado</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Gerundio compuesto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7btt" colspan="4">Personales</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-eiws">Formas simples</td>
    <td class="tg-7btt" colspan="2">Indicativo</td>
    <td class="tg-fymr">Formas compuestas</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-r9b6">Presente</td>
    <td class="tg-yj5y"><span style="font-style:italic">amas</span> / <span style="font-style:italic">amás</span></td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">has amado</td>
    <td class="tg-m223">Pret. perfecto compuesto<br>Antepresente</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-b7v7">Pret. imperfecto<br>Copretérito</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amabas</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">habías amado</td>
    <td class="tg-73oq">Pret. pluscuamperfecto<br>Antecopretérito</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-b7v7">Pret. perfecto simple<br>Pretérito</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amaste</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">hubiste amado</td>
    <td class="tg-73oq">Pret. anterior<br>Antepretérito</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-b7v7">Futuro simple<br>Futuro</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amarás</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">habrás amado</td>
    <td class="tg-73oq">Futuro compuesto<br>Antefuturo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-b7v7">Condicional simple<br>Pospretérito</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amarías</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">habrías amado</td>
    <td class="tg-73oq">Condicional compuesto<br>Antepospretérito</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-6ic8">Formas simples</td>
    <td class="tg-7btt" colspan="2">Subjuntivo</td>
    <td class="tg-mcqj">Formas compuestas</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dvpl">Presente</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">ames</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">hayas amado</td>
    <td class="tg-73oq">Pret. perfecto compuesto<br>Antepresente</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dvpl">Pret. imperfecto<br>Pretérito</td>
    <td class="tg-yj5y"><span style="font-style:italic">amaras</span> o <span style="font-style:italic">amases</span></td>
    <td class="tg-yj5y"><span style="font-style:italic">hubieras</span> o <span style="font-style:italic">hubieses amado</span><br></td>
    <td class="tg-73oq">Pret. pluscuamperfecto<br>Antecopretérito</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-dvpl">Futuro simple<br>Futuro</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">amares</td>
    <td class="tg-fbe1">hubieres amado</td>
    <td class="tg-73oq">Futuro compuesto<br>Antefuturo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7btt" colspan="4">Imperativo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yj5y" colspan="4"><span style="font-style:italic">ama </span>/ <span style="font-style:italic">amá</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So how do I look at the table?  Do I click on "Run code snippet"?  "Expand snippet"?

Comment: @aparente001 First, click "Run code snippet" to allow your browser to render the table. You can see then a narrow view of the table, and, scrolling, the rest. But I think you see it the best clicking "Full page" (to the right). Depending on your screen, you'll be able to see all or almost all.