# Is it possible to make tables without markdown?

Tags: support, markdown, tables

I wanted to edit [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71629/3936) replace the bulleted list with a table. The answers to [other questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/166586) [clearly indicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138946/166586) that this isn't supported by markdown. I tried to make an HTML table, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Given that tables have no markdown support, are there any other ways to make tables on SE sites?

Comment: no (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: Even though its not a duplicate question, the answers to the others question covers what this is asking, thus closing as duplciate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [this awesome online tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html), you can create ASCII tables, that works pretty well in StackExchange sites:

```
+-----------------------------------+---------+--------+
|               Col1                |  Col2   | NumCol |
+-----------------------------------+---------+--------+
| Value 1                           | Value 2 |    123 |
| This is a row with only one cell  |         |        |
| This row is testing html entities | Test    |     45 |
+-----------------------------------+---------+--------+
```