# Should numbered lists be required to be sequential?

Tags: feature-request, list

Is there a way to override the Numbered List Tool's need to make numbers sequential?

There are times that I really appreciate the fact that it's smart enough to make the numbers sequential regardless of what I type... and then, occasionally in answers, sometimes I want to refer to something in the question using the list format but only want to mention two or three of the points being discussed that aren't necessarily sequential which requires not using the list tool at all.

As an example, on ELL, a user asks a question about the use of a phrase, they list four options:

1. Option 1
2. Option 2
3. Option 3
4. Option 4

In my response, I might say that Options 2 and 4 are fine but that Options 1 and 3 should be changed as follows:

1. Option1!
2. Option3?

Unfortunately, even though I'm talking about Option 3, the system has overridden the "3." that I typed and has converted it to "2.".

So, there are two parts to this question...

4. is there a way to override the tool's OCD need to make the numbers sequential and
5. if not, is this the behavior we want?

Is there a third way that allows both the magic of the simple n+1 sequence and the freedom to override the computer that thinks it knows better than I what I want?

Also...

9. I know that if I put non-list text between the list items, that's a work-around but it's not really the solution I'm interested in.

Comment: re "is there a way to override the tool": [escape the "."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234384/how-to-start-list-at-certain-number). However, this breaks list formatting altogether.