How can I make a reversed numbered list in a question or answer?
Numbered lists are easy:

Item1
Item2

This is how it looks when I'm typing this question:

Reversed numbered lists are not that easy:

Item2
Item1

This is how it looks when I'm typing this question:

As you see, I want "2, 1" and I get "2, 3".
Are there any plans implementing reversed numbered lists?

Maybe the easiest way to support that is by allowing HTML with <li value="2"> but at the moment only <a> and <img> tags are allowed to have attributes, any other tags with attributes will be stripped. Adding this might have side-effects on other content on the page. I wouldn't hold my breath until this is implemented.

Note that there is a workaround when you need control over the numbers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234385

https://talk.commonmark.org/t/descending-ordered-lists/1068/7, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30106203/11107541. if commonmark doesn't support it, dunno how you're gonna get it from MarkDig except as an extension.

@rene:  Thanks for your quick reply, but your solution consists of simply stopping the numbering feature (meaning that I must end my lines with two spaces in order to go to the next line).

@starball: I tried, starting a line with 1-., as mentioned in your URL, but it seems not to work here. (Pardon my ignorance, but I have no idea what commonmark is)

@Dominique I didn't mean to link to /7 in that discourse thread. it just happened because I was scrolled to that point. it's a thread on extensions to commonmark (see the tag).

@Dominique commonmark is the standard/dialect of markdown that stack exchange uses on the Q&A sites for posts.

What exactly is the practical use case for this?

I dislike the workarounds that rely on escaped text. At that point, you might as well dispense with the pretense of a numbered list entirely, and use something more descriptive that won't inadvertently render as a list if you somehow lose the escaping. E.g.,
3 verses remaining: sing,

Second stage is cut
We're now in orbit
Stabilizers up
Running perfect
Starting to collect
Requested data
"What will it affect
When all is done?"
Thinks Major Tom

2 verses remaining: sing,

Back at ground control
There is a problem
"Go to rockets full"
Not responding
"Hello Major Tom
Are you receiving?
Turn the thrusters on
We're standing by"
There's no reply

1 verse remaining: sing,

Far beneath the ship
The world is mourning
They don't realize
He's alive
No one understands
But Major Tom sees
"Now the light commands
This is my home
I'm coming home"

That said... If you're determined to achieve the appearance of an inverted list, the CommonMark spec provides an option: use a separate list for each list item.
4. Four
<!-- -->
3. Three
<!-- -->
2. Two
<!-- -->
1. One
   Earth below us
   Drifting, falling
   Floating weightless
   Calling, calling home


Four


Three


Two


One
Earth below us
Drifting, falling
Floating weightless
Calling, calling home


Here is a reverse numbered list.
3. Item three
2. Item two
1. Item one
Markdown:
3\. Item three  
2\. Item two    
1\. Item one  
            ^^-- two spaces after each item

I don't think that's an unreasonable workaround, assuming your list items are short.
Because of the workaround, you do lose the nice indenting and line spacing:
3. If the text here is really long and it has to line wrap, it falls immediately to the margin instead of the nice indenting you might expect otherwise, and it is just treated like a sentence in this paragraph unless you add a line break before the next item.
2. Item two
1. Item one
Compared to wrongly numbered but nicely formatted:

If the text here is really long and it has to line wrap, it is indented nicely and still has a bit of padding before the next item in the list. But the numbers don't obey.
Item two
Item one

If your content is beefier, or you are concerned about accessibility, I might suggest it deserves a Markdown table rather than an ordered list. Then you can put whatever numbers you want in each cell, still get the benefit of formatting and padding, and don't mess with screen readers.









3
If the text here is really long and it has to line wrap, it is indented nicely and still has a bit of padding before the next item in the list.


2
Item two


1
Item one



As mentioned in the comments, there are extensions to Markdown that can make this work easier, but they aren't implemented here. The other answer aside from this one on Stack Overflow is worth a read, too, as well as this post on the CommonMark Discussion forum.

By escaping the list, you lose the semantic information too, which means that screen readers won't be able to navigate it as well. (Using a table, however, would allow other screen reader features to be used.)

For more information about the table approach, see Hey, It’s Still OK to Use Tables. (Excerpt: "If you only have one axis of information, use a list." – but in the face of technical restrictions like we have on Stack Exchange, the other stuff in the article applies.)

For bigger lists use this Excel VBA macro for generating a Markdown table
