# Is there a path to Stack Exchange's markdown converging with GitHub's?

Tags: discussion, markdown

The markdown used on Stack Exchange and the one used on GitHub are fairly similar, but have some subtle differences. For example, on GitHub, you can add ```` ``` ```` before and after a set of lines to format them as code, but that doesn't work on Stack Exchange.

As someone who writes markdown on both sites, I find these subtle differences inhibit the development of muscle memory (e.g. I often type ```` ``` ```` on Stack Exchange, only to realize (again) that it doesn't work and erase and correct it).

Is there any plan /  path forward to converge these two flavours of Markdown?

**Note:** I gave ```` ``` ```` as an example, but I'm asking about general convergence between the two flavours, rather than one particular extension.

Comment: Why fix something that is not broken? SE markdown is working fine, no need to now change it to be something that 99.999% of the users are not familiar with.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You could leave it as an undocumented feature? After all, it doesn't break anything... :)

Comment: @SonicWizard sounds like OP wants to merge them, not only add new features to SE markdown, which means also changing/removing things in the existing markdown.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It didn't come across to me as that type of request.

Comment: Related "markdown flavor" discussion: [Time to fork Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230014/241919)

Comment: Stack using an undocumented difficult-to-formalize markup they call "Markdown" is indeed problematic, but not problematic enough that it's likely to change soon.