# Why aren't tables in posts supported via markdown or as raw html?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, tables

Wanting to display information in a table is not that uncommon, particularly so for SQL questions on stackoverflow (SQL deals with *tables* of data).

There is support for tables in various markdown libraries, and it's pretty straightforward, so:

1. Why can't we just support it? What's the big deal?
2. If there is a *good* reason, why can't the `<table>` tag (and the various row/column tags) be allowed as raw html?

---

Related questions, but not duplicates IMHO because there doesn't seem to be a good *reason* put forward for "why not":

- [Can we add Markdown support for tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138946/can-we-add-markdown-support-for-tables)
- [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)

Comment: [Reason.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228464)

Comment: @animuson ahhh crap :( thx.

Comment: Is it straightforward though? Or is that bias because you've tried and tried again with its arcane formatting?