# Please fix that Table Overflow

Tags: feature-request, design, tables

This is how a Stack Exchange question looks like after adding `table {border: 3px solid red;}` (i.e. each element with red border is a table):

[image]

There are definitely too many tables. Some of them even have three levels of nesting. Also, tables should not be used for things which aren't tabular data.

I realize that [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3110/310998) has been asked before, but that was 7 years ago, and things changed since than (for example, Flexbox didn't exist back then).

Comment: It does make my heart sink a little every time I "view source" / "inspect" etc.

Comment: Tables are easier to maintain as far as I remember. If that means less development time for  bug fixes, guess it's for the best.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Uh, no, it's just the opposite.

Comment: @Gothdo: Do you have an alternative suggestion to maintain the structure, or is your [meta-tag:feature-request] just to "remove the tabular structure"?

Comment: @Werner My suggestion is to use flexbox instead. Why did you remove the [semantics] tag?

Comment: @Gothdo: [meta-tag:semantics] had no description with it and I thought your question already included [meta-tag:design], which covered the [meta-tag:feature-request]. If you think [meta-tag:semantics] should remain, [update/edit the tag info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/semantics/info).

Comment: I think you could sell the idea easier if you took a post html markup, edited it, then made a proof-of-concept that use the api to insert the posts contents into the new layout.

Comment: I'm not particularly a table advocate here and AFAIK nobody else on the team is either, but... is there an actual issue with this other than personal preference/semantics?

Comment: FWIW, we've given some thought/attempts to removing tables from comments, at least. It apparently turned out to be more painful than expected, though I'm not immediately familiar with the specifics.

Comment: I'm firmly convinced that the "use divs not tables" crowd has never actually stood up a real web page and observed how difficult it is to get plain divs to behave the way you want them to.

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem here? Religion doesn't count.

Comment: I could buy an accessibility argument if one were made. With data.